# Differences between /media/Home and /home

Tags: mount, backup, home-directory, rsync

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I just made a seperate home partition labeled Home and copied the contents over with rsync:

```
sudo rsync -aXS --progress --exclude='/*/.gvfs' /home/. /media/Home/.
```

Then when I executed the command:

```
sudo diff -q -r  /home /media/Home -x ".gvfs/*"
```

I got many differences. So I used the rsync command a few more times in different times but it still shows many differences. I get the Spotify and Firefox differences as they're either cache files made in /home after using rsync or cache files removed from /home after using rsync that stayed in /media/Home.
However, I got a few differences in matplotlib in anaconda3 folder, gnome-session-monitor, gnome-shell and gnome-calculator that I'm concerned about:

```
diff: /home/oussema/anaconda3/pkgs/matplotlib-2.1.2-py36h0e671d2_0/lib/libtcl.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/anaconda3/pkgs/matplotlib-2.1.2-py36h0e671d2_0/lib/libtcl.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/anaconda3/pkgs/matplotlib-2.1.2-py36h0e671d2_0/lib/libtk.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/anaconda3/pkgs/matplotlib-2.1.2-py36h0e671d2_0/lib/libtk.so: No such file or directory
Only in /home/oussema: .gvfs
Files /home/oussema/.local/share/gnome-shell/application_state and /media/Home/oussema/.local/share/gnome-shell/application_state differ
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/167/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/167/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/167/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/167/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/167/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/167/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/167/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/167/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/167/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/167/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/167/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/167/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/167/.local/share/themes: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/167/.local/share/themes: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/167/.themes: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/167/.themes: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/170/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/170/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/170/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/170/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/170/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/170/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/170/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/170/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/170/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/170/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/170/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/170/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/170/.local/share/themes: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/170/.local/share/themes: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/170/.themes: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/170/.themes: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/gio-modules/libdconfsettings.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/gio-modules/libdconfsettings.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognomeproxy.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognomeproxy.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognutls.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognutls.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-am-et.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-am-et.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-broadway.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-broadway.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-cedilla.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-cedilla.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-cyrillic-translit.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-cyrillic-translit.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-fcitx.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-fcitx.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-ibus.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-ibus.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-inuktitut.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-inuktitut.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-ipa.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-ipa.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-multipress.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-multipress.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-thai.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-thai.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-ti-er.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-ti-er.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-ti-et.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-ti-et.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-viqr.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-viqr.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-xim.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/common/.cache/immodules/im-xim.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/current/.local/share/themes: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/current/.local/share/themes: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/current/.themes: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-calculator/current/.themes: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/39/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/39/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/39/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/39/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/39/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/39/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/39/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/39/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/39/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/39/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/39/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/39/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/39/.local/share/themes: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/39/.local/share/themes: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/39/.themes: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/39/.themes: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/41/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/41/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/41/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/41/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/41/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/41/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/41/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/41/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/41/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/41/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/41/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/41/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/41/.local/share/themes: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/41/.local/share/themes: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/41/.themes: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/41/.themes: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/gio-modules/libdconfsettings.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/gio-modules/libdconfsettings.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognomeproxy.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognomeproxy.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognutls.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiognutls.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/gio-modules/libgiolibproxy.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-am-et.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-am-et.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-broadway.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-broadway.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-cedilla.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-cedilla.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-cyrillic-translit.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-cyrillic-translit.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-fcitx.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-fcitx.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-ibus.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-ibus.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-inuktitut.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-inuktitut.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-ipa.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-ipa.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-multipress.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-multipress.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-thai.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-thai.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-ti-er.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-ti-er.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-ti-et.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-ti-et.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-viqr.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-viqr.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-xim.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/common/.cache/immodules/im-xim.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-Black/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursors: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/current/.local/share/icons/DMZ-White/index.theme: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/current/.local/share/themes: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/current/.local/share/themes: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/current/.themes: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/snap/gnome-system-monitor/current/.themes: No such file or directory
```

[Here is the full output of the diff command.](https://pastebin.com/C6kAJT8p)
I want to know whether it's safe to just use fstab to switch /media/Home into /home?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you rsync a user's home directory, you need to do that from another user's log-in *while the user being rsynced is logged off* as the home directory will constantly change due to all the applications you've got running.

It is also always wise to have 2 users on a system: a user and an admin: the normal user is for your everyday use and the admin to do admin stuff or when your other user has profile issues.

*Alternatively:*

- just boot from a live USB and have a completely static rsync
- boot from a CloneZilla Live USB and take a partition image.

Comment: Are there different home directories for different users? I am syncing the whole /home folder not just /home/oussema so I believe the problem will still be there even with a different user

Comment: I think I'll just exclude .cache from my diff command and see if there are any other differences

Comment: **I think not:** create a new user and then rsync `/home/oussema` instead of `/home/.`  **:-)**

Comment: Ok, but then the new user's home will still be in the root filesystem partition

Comment: Are cache files really **that necessary**? Can't I just use something like ` sudo diff -q -r /home /media/Home -x ".gvfs/*" -x".cache/*"
` and spare myself the trouble?

Comment: Ok, I tried the command above and I still had this: `diff: /home/oussema/anaconda3/pkgs/matplotlib-2.1.2-py36h0e671d2_0/lib/libtcl.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/anaconda3/pkgs/matplotlib-2.1.2-py36h0e671d2_0/lib/libtcl.so: No such file or directory
diff: /home/oussema/anaconda3/pkgs/matplotlib-2.1.2-py36h0e671d2_0/lib/libtk.so: No such file or directory
diff: /media/Home/oussema/anaconda3/pkgs/matplotlib-2.1.2-py36h0e671d2_0/lib/libtk.so: No such file or directory
` Any advice?

Comment: Was oussema logged off while your were running this from oussema-admin?

Comment: No. You know what? Can I do this from a live USB? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes!  Of course!!!  Answer updated: if you're booting from USB, boot from a CloneZilla USB...  **;-)**  Don't forget to accept!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78266/discussion-between-oussema-and-fabby).